# jQuery: Split String at certain element

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm creating a `read more` function.* I want to split my html code at the point where `<span id="more-NUMBER"></span>` happens. Then I want to move the before and after sections.

The problem I'm running into is writing the regex in a way that can account for the numbers placed in the id. Here's what I'm starting with:

```
var text = jQuery('p').html().split('<span id="more-/\d+/"></span>');
text[0].appendTo('.red-text');
text[1].appendTo('.blue-text');
```

Here's a starter Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/samwisegrangee/r8c4urht/

*I had one that worked previously when our Wordpress site used a `<!--more-->` comment to create a `read more`. You can view that solution here: https://codepen.io/samwisegrangee/pen/aWGJOO

Comment: `split('<span id="more-/\d+/"></span>');`  That's not a regEx.. it's just a string.

Comment: Is there a way to make my `.split()` happen regardless of the number in that string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a regular expression is denoted by forward slashes (`/.../`) rather than quotes. Second, in the regex you would need to escape the backslash in `</span>`.

```
/<span id="more-\d+"><\/span>/
```

That's not quite all. Your appends aren't working either, so here's some final corrected code:

```
var regex = /<span id="more-\d+"><\/span>/;
var text = jQuery('.featured-text p').html().split(regex);
jQuery('.red-text').html(text[0]);
jQuery('.blue-text').html(text[1]);
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/xt0m4qzx/8/)**

Answer (score 0):

> id="more-/\d+/"

Backslash is the escape character. So `\"` not `/"`. What is the `/` in `more-/` supposed to do?

[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/Bv0B5J/2).

Comment: The "more-" is just the constant part of the `id`. The number changes but it will always start off with `more-`.